# How to bound CSS3 animation to class

Tags: css

I'm new to css so possible asking question in wrong way.
I have a simple pulsating animation. In CSS file is this code:

```
.pulsor_red {
    -webkit-animation: pulsate .4s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: pulsate .4s infinite alternate;
    -animation: pulsate .4s infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    from { box-shadow: 0 0 8px red; }
    to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px red; }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulsate {
    from { box-shadow: 0 0 10px red; }
    to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px red; }
}
@keyframes pulsate {
    from { box-shadow: 0 0 10px red; }
    to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px red; }
}

.pulsor_orange {
    -webkit-animation: pulsate .4s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: pulsate .4s infinite alternate;
    -animation: pulsate .4s infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    from { box-shadow: 0 0 8px #ffac00; }
    to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ffac00; }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulsate {
    from { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffac00; }
    to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ffac00; }
}
@keyframes pulsate {
    from { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffac00; }
    to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ffac00; }
}
```

I would like to set class on one div `pulsor_red` and to other one `pulsor_orange` for one pulsating red and other orange (#ffac00).
How to do it?

[click for jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u512spu4/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use unique names for both animations (notice the `first` and `second`):

```css
div{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}

.pulsor_red {
    -webkit-animation: first .4s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: first .4s infinite alternate;
    -animation: first .4s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes first {
    from { box-shadow: 0 0 8px red; }
    to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px red; }
}

@-moz-keyframes first {
    from { box-shadow: 0 0 10px red; }
    to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px red; }
}

@keyframes first {
    from { box-shadow: 0 0 10px red; }
    to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px red; }
}

.pulsor_orange {
    -webkit-animation: second .4s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: second .4s infinite alternate;
    -animation: second .4s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes second {
    from { box-shadow: 0 0 8px #ffac00; }
    to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ffac00; }
}

@-moz-keyframes second {
    from { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffac00; }
    to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ffac00; }
}

@keyframes second {
    from { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffac00; }
    to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ffac00; }
}
```

```html
<div class="pulsor_red">xxxxxx</div>
<div class="pulsor_orange">yyyyyy</div>
```